# SQLAlchemy decimal precision

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The documentation at sqlalchemy gives an example:

```
class sqlalchemy.types.DECIMAL(precision=None, scale=None, asdecimal=True)
```

What values other than None can you use for precision? I don't really understand how to set up the decimal precision.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Numeric)

**precision** – the numeric precision for use in DDL CREATE TABLE

If you want to know which values are possible, check W3Schools for SQL data types: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp

In this case:

*DECIMAL(p,s)*: Exact numerical, precision p, scale s. Example: decimal(5,2) is a number that has 3 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal

Comment: if I use price = db.Column(DECIMAL(10,2)) it works. but if i change it to price = db.Column(DECIMAL(precision=10, scale=2)) not work at all? what's the problem here?

Comment: Always use Integers in cents for prices and then divide by 100 later for formatting.  Otherwise things get weird calculating fractions of pennies.

Comment: @user1071182 that's not much help, the second you divide by 100 it becomes a float with a variable amount of decimal points

Comment: @NikolaJankovic It doesn't if you divide it by 100.

Comment: I think it's a bit inaccurate, at least in case of postgres. From the docs: `The precision of a numeric is the total count of significant digits in the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both sides of the decimal point.` Precision being total number of digits, not just the ones to the left